# Access variables of external subprogram in Python with Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

The main.py calls several subprograms that are located in other files. As I am debugging a subprogram I want to access the local variables of the subprogram. In the example below the subprogram is stopped by `sys.exit()` and the variable `a` is not accessible from the console. How can I access the variables of sub.py from the Spyder console?

Minimal example:

**main.py**

```
import sub
b=sub.sub1()
```

**sub.py**

```
def sub1():
 a=1
 sys.exit()
```

I use Spyder 5.2 with WinPython 3.9.5.0 and the programs are used without installation on Win10Pro version 21H1.

Comment: Do you want to access the attributes for use in another function or are you just trying to see what values they hold?  If the latter, use Spyder's debug capability.  In the first case, you would have to enable the sub.py function to retun a to the calling function.

Comment: I do not want to return variables to the calling function. How can I access the variables from the console?

Comment: Use the debugger

Comment: how does this give me access to the variables?

Comment: you would have to use `return a` to get it as `b = sub.sub1()` but if you use `sys.exit()` then all your code should stoped and `b = ` is useless. Maybe you should use `global  a` to assign value to external/global variable in module.

Comment: There are many variables in the subprogram and only one return variable. It is not comfortable if always a variable has to be declared as global, they are needed as local variables. Also it is not possible to put all code in a single file in case of large code.

Comment: I think you should call the `brealpoint()` function at the point you want to stop your program and check your variables. That starts Spyder's debugger, which allows to inspect the internals of your code.

Comment: thats a solution, but not very comfortable to press 12 keys to place a stop signal

Comment: how can I rerun the code without always typing ```!exit``` in the console after stopping by ```breakpoint()```